# Oracle DB Errors when Trying to import a Dump File

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, mysql

Hi I am trying to import a dump file but im getting the same errors every time, here is what commands I have Used So far:

```
C:\Users\CCT>sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> create tablespace CCTADMIN datafile ‘D:\OracleDB\CCTADMIN.dbf’ size 2G autoextend on maxsize 5G;
SQL> create user wrosa identified by wrosa1; 
SQL> grant connect, resource, dba to wrosa;
SQL> grant create materialized view to wrosa;
```

This next line didnt actually created my directory so i wen and created my directory manually on Windows.

```
SQL> create directory CCT_IMPORT as ‘D:\OracleDB \TEMP’;
SQL> grant read, write on directory CCT_IMPORT to wrosa;
D:\OracleDB \TEMP>impdp wrosa/wrosa1 directory=CCT_IMPORT dumpfile=CCTADMIN4.dmp logfile=impdpWROSA.log remap_schema=CCTADMIN:WROSA remap_tablespace=SOE:CCTADMIN
```

After that i get the following error

```
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
```

I Appreciate your time looking at this.
Thanks

Comment: look at your path for cct_import. you have a space after "oracledb"

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check CCT_IMPORT directory exists or not? If it exists then wrosa user is having privilege of read,write on same directory or not? Check path of directory proper set or not. Without having directory permission you cannot be able to perform datapump.